# How to convert DWG to STP or IGES via any console/command line

Tags: console, autodesk, dwg, step

I am trying to convert a Autocad DWG file to stp or iges file which would mean 2D to 3D.

What I found out so far is that you can convert them via GUI on Autocad mechanical with the command stepout/igesout. So I tried to use it on AcCoreConsole but it seems the commands are unexisting. Does someone have any clue where or how I could convert them via any Console

Comment: STEP file format is not strong on drafting. Expect many standard drafting entities (like hatches and dimensions) missing.